# Eliminating NOT IN from query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to eliminate the need to use `NOT IN` in my query:

```
select count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2
    ON T1.DATAID = T2.EXISTING_DOCUMENT
        AND T1.ownerid = -2000 
        AND T1.SUBTYPE = 144 
        AND T1.dataid NOT IN (SELECT T3.dataid 
                           FROM   TABLE3 T3
                           WHERE  T3.ID = 123)
```

Reason: I read that `NOT IN` is slow (+500k rows) and doesn't use indices

I tried:

```
select count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
ON T1.DATAID = T2.EXISTING_DOCUMENT
        AND T1.ownerid = -2000 
        AND T1.SUBTYPE = 144 
left outer join TABLE3 T3 
 on T3.ancestorid = T1.dataid
    where T3.ID = 123
```

Comment: IS NULL is missing.

Comment: did you review the explain plan?  did you experience a slow response?  You may investigate MINUS as an operator as well.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `SELECT T1.dataid FROM   TABLE3 ...`  or `SELECT T3.dataid FROM   TABLE3 ...` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan you're right I made a mistake, updated post.

Comment: Where did you read that about `NOT IN`? It is either a really old or a plain wrong article (perhaps both).

Comment: As far as I know, `NOT IN ()` is slow not because of index use, but because it's a RBAR operation. Is that not correct?

Comment: A `not in (subquery)` may have to use a filtered-loop operation if the key is nullable. Defining the key as `not null` or adding an `and xyz is not null` to the subquery tends to fix that (but also changes the logic of the query - although it's usually what the writer of the query actually wanted.)

Comment: How many rows does the sub-select on T3 return? Is there an index on column ID on T3? How long does the T3 select statement take if you run it by itself?

Comment: As written above, I believe the query will return all rows from `table1` and a bunch of `NULL`s for `table2` results. Is this the intent?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT IN` does use indices, at least in a competent database such as Oracle.  However, you can write this using `join`s if you prefer.

But, why doesn't this do what you want?

```
select count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 T1
WHERE T1.ownerid = -2000 AND T1.SUBTYPE = 144;
```

You are using a `LEFT JOIN`, so the only difference is that your version counts duplicates in `TABLE2`.  But that may not really apply.

Your query doesn't really make sense, because you are comparing `T1.dataid` to `T1.dataid`.  But, further, the comparison to `Table3` has no impact on the result.  So, you can just remove it:

```
select count(*) 
FROM TABLE1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     TABLE2 T2
     ON T1.DATAID = T2.EXISTING_DOCUMENT AND
        T1.ownerid = -2000 AND
        T1.SUBTYPE = 144 ;
```

Because of the `LEFT JOIN`, filtering in the `ON` clause will not remove any rows.  And because it is `NOT IN`, there is no possibility of duplication.

Comment: I made a mistake in my original post in that the subquery should be `SELECT T3.dataid 
                           FROM   TABLE3 T3
                           WHERE  T3.ID = 123` does this change anything?

Comment: Hey sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding why you say I don't need the last `AND` statement at all.

Comment: @Batman . . . No.  The condition on `T3` doesn't change anything.  You have a `left join` so that condition in the `on` clause cannot change the row count.

Comment: I think it may change the intent, though. The `JOIN` looks like an improperly written `JOIN`. It _seems_ the OP wants to exclude records from the final result set where `t1.dataid` doesn't match the `t3.dataid` where `t3.id=123`. But that's my assumption, and you know what they say about those. :-/

Comment: @Shawn i think your assumption is correct. I'm looking at a query written by someone else so I'm also trying to understand their intent.

Comment: Figuring intent of someone else's query is always fun. That's why well-documented requirements are a coder's best friend. Or at least good comments. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WHERE x IS NULL` filter to emulate a `NOT IN`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e02d/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ownerid int, subtype int, dataid int, note varchar(100) ) ;
INSERT INTO t1 ( ownerid, subtype, dataid, note )
SELECT 1 as ownerid, 1 as subtype, 1 as dataid, 'WHERE Filter' as note FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -2000,  1,1, 'IN WHERE Filter' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -2000,144,1, 'IN WHERE, NOT IN t3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -2000,144,2, 'IN WHERE, IN t3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -2000,144,3, 'IN WHERE, NOT IN t3' FROM DUAL
;

CREATE TABLE t2 ( existing_document int, note varchar(100) ) ;
INSERT INTO t2 (existing_document, note)
SELECT 1 as existing_document, 'JOIN t1' as note FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'JOIN t1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'JOIN t1, DUPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'JOIN t1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'JOIN t1, DUPE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'NOT JOIN t1' FROM DUAL
;

CREATE TABLE t3 ( id int, dataid int, note varchar(100) ) ;
INSERT INTO t3 (id, dataid, note)
SELECT 1 as id, 1 as dataid, 'No filter. No match.' as note FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 4, 'No filter. No match t1.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123,2,'Match JOIN filter. Match t1' FROM DUAL
;
```

Read the notes in the setup to view how I'm building up the data. It's very simple and not a lot to count, but it should give you an idea on how this data works together.

**Query**:

```
SELECT *  /* Not counting here so you can see what's supposed to be counted. */
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.dataid = t2.EXISTING_DOCUMENT
LEFT OUTER JOIN t3 ON t1.dataid = t3.dataid
  AND t3.ID = 123
WHERE t1.ownerid = -2000
  AND t1.subtype = 144
  AND t3.dataid IS NULL /* This is the NOT IN */
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e02d/2/0)**:

```
| OWNERID | SUBTYPE | DATAID |                NOTE | EXISTING_DOCUMENT |          NOTE |     ID | DATAID |   NOTE |
|---------|---------|--------|---------------------|-------------------|---------------|--------|--------|--------|
|   -2000 |     144 |      1 | IN WHERE, NOT IN t3 |                 1 |       JOIN t1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   -2000 |     144 |      3 | IN WHERE, NOT IN t3 |                 3 |       JOIN t1 | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|   -2000 |     144 |      3 | IN WHERE, NOT IN t3 |                 3 | JOIN t1, DUPE | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

The optimizer usually runs very well with the `WHERE x IS NULL` syntax and indexes should still apply, but if Oracle is able to make use of the indexes in the `NOT IN`, that is a big plus. If you're dealing with a lot of data, the `IS NULL` method can be a lot faster. The best check is to just test it with your actual data.

Comment: Looking back at my query this morning, I realized I made several assumptions about the intent of your original query. 1) I used an `INNER JOIN` on `table2` because I assumed you wanted just rows from `table1` that had an `Existing_Document` in `table2. Change that back to a `LEFT JOIN`. 2) I assumed that you wanted to exclude records from `table1` (and `table2` by extension) that didn't exist for a `dataid` that had a `t3.id=123`.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eeef3/1 >>> `table2` switched to `LEFT JOIN` and another record added to `table1` that doesn't match either `table2` or `table3`.

Comment: I noticed that if I go with this approach I can't add more inner joins if I needed to. For example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eeef3/2

Comment: @Batman Think of what an `INNER JOIN` does though. It is a limiter. Think of what data you want to get to and then formulate your `JOIN`s from there. What data do you want to show and how do you want to limit it?

Comment: @Batman Looking at the fiddle, make sure your `JOIN`s go above your `WHERE`.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/64341/1  <<< Keep in mind this can also add to your counts -- ie if you have 3 t4 records that match 1 t1 record, it would probably increase your count(*) by +2. Make sure that's what you're looking to count.

Answer (score 0):

how about NOT EXISTS?

```
select count(*) 
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 T2
  ON T1.DATAID = T2.EXISTING_DOCUMENT
    AND T1.ownerid = -2000 
    AND T1.SUBTYPE = 144 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM TABLE3 T3
                       WHERE  T3.ID = 123
                         AND T3.dataid = T1.dataid)
```